# Add button to EntryElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have created an EntryElement in which the user enters a phone number.How can I add a button at the end of the element so that the user can press the button and make a call?

Comment: Why not make that an answer instead of a comment? It's exactly what to do!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new element that is a subclass of an EntryElement, override the get cell method and add to the accessoryView the button .

Comment: I you dont know how to get back to the application after that the conversation is finished, then take a look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264065/is-it-possible-to-go-back-automatically-into-the-application-after-calling-a-num

Comment: The property AccessoryView of the cell is null.Instead I added the button to the subviews of the cell as `_cell.Subviews[0].AddSubview(btn)`. Is this the same?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't exactly answer the question but I struggled for quite a while until I found the answer by @Janub which put me on the right track. Here is the code that I currently have working.

```
public class NextNumericCell : EntryElement
{
    readonly EventHandler handler;
    public NextNumericCell (string caption, string placeholder, string value, EventHandler onClick ) : base(caption,placeholder,value) 
    {
        handler = onClick;
    }

    protected override UITextField CreateTextField (CGRect frame)
    {
        var textField = base.CreateTextField (frame);
        var toolBar = new UIToolbar (new CGRect (0, 0, frame.Width, 35));
        var spacerButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
        var buttonTitle = ReturnKeyType == null ? "SetButtonTitle" : ReturnKeyType.ToString ();
        var nextButton = new UIBarButtonItem (buttonTitle, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, handler);
        toolBar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem [] { spacerButton, nextButton };
        textField.InputAccessoryView = toolBar;
        return textField;
    }
}
```